# SharePoint - Scheduled Workflows

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

Is there any 'out of the box' feature in SharePoint to allow you to schedule a workflow?

Answer (score 2):

No there is no OTB feature to do that, but depending on the workflow you might be able to fake it.

If it's a SharePoint Designer workflow you've created that you want to run at certain intervals. Then you can make the following changes to it:

1. Make it run automatically when the
   item is changed.
2. When it's done with the real
   functionality then make a delay and
   after the delay modify the item and
   stop.

A new instance of the workflow will then spawn due to the modification